# Accessing router access point with dynamic IP

Tags: wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I added a Linksys wireless router and set it as an access point (which gets IP automaticall).

How can I now access it's settings panel? I don't know the IP.

I looked in the main router's devices list and I don't see it there... only see my computer which is actually connected to the new access point... and the main router sees the computer directly and shows me its local ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the Tomato firmware settings for the Access Point (second router) I have actually set Dynamic option for WAN - which doesn't matter or can actually be harmful. I didn't realize that I have to update the LAN settings a bit below so I just left defaults here ... and it had 192.168.1.1 address!! The same as the main router... :( Not sure how this worked... but I did have some issues (had to reset main router a few times since yesterday)...

Now I have set 192.168.1.200 as the new router's IP address and it looks fine.

So this was quite a stupid mistake but I haven't done this in a while...

Sorry for wasting your time here... but maybe we did learn something... that it's possible for this setup to somewhat work and thus making issue hard to detect. Too bad it worked at all or I could find the problem sooner. Otherwise it was good because I learned about Angry IP Scanner, nmap and also that there are really some wireless access points that don't get IP assigned... just not WRT54GL.

UPDATE: something else is interesting and it looks like that's how it works:
I still see 192.168.1.1 as the gateway while connected to newly setup second router. But now everything works and I can connect to it on 192.168.1.200. So the reported gateway is the IP of the main router, not the second one used as an "access point". Good to know, I also remembered it that way and that's also why it wasn't strange to me to see 192.168.1.1 as the gateway before.

Thank you all again!

Comment: how did you access the firmware settings for your secondary router in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the network and accessing the new wireless router, its IP is the same as your gateway IP address.

The linksys will acquire a dynamic IP address from the primary router, but you would only need to know that address if you were attached to that primary router. Even then, the Linksys might be configured not to allow access to the admin panels from outside.

In all likelihood, if your computer IP is something like 192.168.1.101 the Linksys router will be 192.168.1.1 (and if it's 192.168.0.101 it would be 192.168.0.1 etc).

Comment: 192.168.1.1 gets me to the main router... not the new access point... :/

Comment: I used that only as an example. What does your gateway show as? (and your computer IP).  Might you still be connected to the old router?

Comment: gateway: 192.168.1.1
my comp: 192.168.1.102

Gateway is normal, I think... because AP is just "AP"... or have I not set something as I should have?

Comment: You seem to be still connected to the old router. Maybe I am assuming too much. You should have your computer either directly plugged into the linksys, or connecting to the linksys via wireless. Also the linksys `WAN` port should be connected to one of the old router `LAN` ports. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm 100% connected to the AP wifi... not the main router...

Comment: is it not possible that I configured that AP as a HUB with wifi? Isn't that how all AP's work? So maybe this access point really doesn't have it's own IP.

Comment: "AP" just means access point and could refer to either of your two devices. Usually Linksys makes routers with wifi; however there COULD exist a hub that has wifi? I don't know... you bought the product. It has no directions or specifications on the box?

Comment: Ok both routers are Linksys WRT54GL. I just set up the second one as an AP (turned off DHCP, gave it dynamic IP) and plugged the cable in one of 4 ports (not WAN).

Comment: from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929438/does-wifi-access-points-have-an-ip-address "Wifi access points need not have an IP address, any more than wired switches and hubs do. However a large number do, as they also act on the IP layer as DHCP servers and network gateways."

Comment: More explanation because maybe it's strange why I have two wifi routers ... one is on the lower floor and I got that new one (=AP in this thread) because of coverage on upper floor. So I'm connected on the second router's wifi now and I see the first (main) router as a gateway.

Comment: Found the issue... my answer below. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Interesting: I still see 192.168.1.1 as the gateway while connected to newly setup second router. But now everything works and I can connect to it on 192.168.1.200.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's two options for you, since your main router won't show you all the device connected to it.

1)

- Connect your computer directly to the wireless AP

  - reset your Linksys wireless router (that you're using as AP)
  - connect to the wifi or wire in to the Lynksys device so you can manage it
  - set a static IP that's within your current network's subnet
  - set it up as AP

2)

- Download [nmap](http://nmap.org/) (or any tool that can ping a network range)
- do a `nmap -sP 192.168.1.*` (assuming your network is 192.168.1.0/24)
- figure out from that list which IP is your wireless AP using

Comment: Yes the first option is most likely what I'll have to do... now it really seems that it doesn't have an IP - that it's just a "hub with wifi" - is that possible? I already ran an IP scanner and haven't found the AP. Will try with nmap as well.

Comment: I checked with `nmap` and it finds just 2 devices (main router and computer)... strange that it misses my phone on 192.168.1.119. Angry IP Scanner does find it... How can that be explained?

Comment: Not sure why nmap didn't find your phone but Angry IP scanner did, could be the fact that Angry IP scanner uses something other than ICMP.  What's the model number of your Linksys device?

Comment: Looking at the other comments, it looks like you have a WRT54GL. Do a [30/30/30](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30) reset. Connect directly to that router with your laptop, and go to `192.168.1.1` with the user name blank/empty and password `admin.

Comment: Did that! And also found the real issue... my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

check gateway for your network in computer: ipconfig (windows), ifconfig (linux)
and try that IP.

It your access point ain't gateway, you could try scan ip, like AngryIPScanner to see all your devices inside network.

Or you could tracert (windows), and see the route.

Comment: yes, gateway IP is that of the main router... tracert shows that packets go straight to that gateway... I did a IP scan and it only detects the gateway and my computer (and phone). I guess the access point doesn't have it's own IP at all (?).